# Getting an error : Notice: Undefined offset

Tags: php

i need to write a small php program to show the below but am getting errors. it need to output the numbers in font size increments of 10's. heres my code so far :

```
<?php
    $sz=array("10px","12px","14px","16px","18px");

    for ($row = 1; $row <= 5; $row++) {

        for ($col = 1; $col <= $row; $col++) {

            echo "<span style='font-size:${sz[$row]}>"; 
        }

        echo "$col","</span>"; 

     }
?>
```

any help greatly appreciated !

heres what I'm hoping to output:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

where the 1 is 10px, 12 is 20px, 123 is 30px and so on...

Comment: The first element of an array is [0], not [1].

Comment: I'm sorry i don't follow?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Could you show what you're expected output is?

Comment: @user3499503 Please click `edit` under the question and add the details, don't try to cram code into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple incorrect things going on here:

1. array index's start with 0
2. You don't have a multidimensional array, so I don't know why you have a nested loop
3. You should use the array itself as the end bound, and not hardcode it

Put that all together...

```
<?php
$sizes =array("10px","12px","14px","16px","18px");

for($i = 0, $l = count($sizes); $i < $l; $i++){
  $size = $sizes[$i];
  $text = $i + 1;

  echo "<span style='font-size:$size'>$text</span><br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: great thank you so much , how do i get it to output :
1
12
123
1234
12345
where the 1 is 10px, 12 is 20px, 123 is 30px and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Array indexes start at 0, not 1.  Your loop at the end tries to access an index of 5, which it cannot.  Since that offset is not defined in the array, you get that notice.

Your array essentially looks like this

```
[0] = 10px
[1] = 12px
[2] = 14px
[3] = 16px
[4] = 18px
```

At some point your script turns `$row` into 5